# How upload image in angular 7 from backend

Tags: node.js, angular, express, mongoose

i can upload image with postman but in angular it doesn't work for me. solution please

> error : cannot read originalname of undefined , in nodejs but with
>   postman its work !

**//backend**

```
var express = require("express")
var router = express.Router();
var userModel = require("../models/userModel")
const jwt= require("jsonwebtoken")
const  bcrypt=require("bcrypt")
var app=express()
var io = require('socket.io-client')('http://localhost:3000/alll')

var  socket = require("socket.io");

var fs=require("fs")
var multer=require("multer")
const upload = multer({dest: __dirname + '/upload/images'});

router.post('/uploads', upload.single('image'), function (req, res) {
  var file = __dirname + '/upload' + req.file.originalname;
  fs.readFile(req.file.path, function (err, data) {
    fs.writeFile(file, data, function (err) {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err); 
        var response = {
          message: 'Sorry, file couldn\'t be uploaded.',
          filename: req.file.originalname
        };
      } else {
        response = {
          message: 'File uploaded successfully',
          filename: req.file.originalname
        };
        res.json(response);
      }
    })
  })
})
router.post("/add",function (req, res) {


        user = new userModel({firstName: req.body.firstName,
          lastName: req.body.lastName ,
          email:req.body.email ,
          password:req.body.password,
          adresse:req.body.adresse,
          verif:'1',role :'user',
          annonces:req.body.annonces,
          pdf: req.body.pdf
        })
        user.save(function(err) {
          if (err) {
            res.send({"state": "not ok", "msg": "err:" + err})
          } else {
            res.send({"state": " ok", "msg": "ajout"})
          }

        })
})
// model : pdf as String
```

**//ts**

```
import {ChangeDetectorRef, Component, OnInit, TemplateRef} from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {UserService} from '../services/user.service';
import {ConnecterComponent} from '../connecter/connecter.component';
import {BsModalRef, BsModalService} from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { FileUploader } from 'ng2-file-upload';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-singin',
  templateUrl: './singin.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./singin.component.css']
})
export class SinginComponent implements OnInit {
  registrationForm: FormGroup;
  submit = false;
  fileSelected: File

emailuser: String;
  modalRef: BsModalRef;

  selectedFiles: FileList;
  currentFileUpload: File;
  imgURL: any;
  imgname;
  errorValidImage = '';
    URL ='http://localhost:3000/users/uploads';
  constructor(private router: Router, private userService: UserService, private formbuilder: FormBuilder , private cd : ChangeDetectorRef, private modalService: BsModalService ) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.registrationForm = this.formbuilder.group({
      email: [ '', [ Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      password: ['', [ Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)]],
      firstName:['',[ Validators.required]],
      lastName: ['', Validators.required],
      adresse:['', Validators.required],
      pdf:[''],

    });

  }
  get f() {
    return this.registrationForm.controls;
  }
 OnSubmit(){


    this.submit = true;
    if (this.registrationForm.invalid) {
     return;
   }
    console.log(this.registrationForm.value)
    localStorage.setItem('var', '1');
    this.userService.updateimagee(this.currentFileUpload).subscribe(res=>{
      this.imgname=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res['filename']));

    this.userService.register(this.registrationForm.value.firstName,this.registrationForm.value.lastName,this.registrationForm.value.email,this.registrationForm.value.password,this.registrationForm.value.adresse,this.registrationForm.value.pdf=this.imgname).subscribe(  res =>  {
    console.log(res['status'])
  });
    this.userService.login(this.registrationForm.value.email,this.registrationForm.value.password).subscribe(res=>{
      localStorage.setItem('var', '1')
      localStorage.setItem('emailuser',JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res['data'])).email)
      this.emailuser=localStorage.getItem('emailuser')
      console.log(res['status'])
      console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res['data'])).token);
      // console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res['data'])).id);
      var iduser = parseInt(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res['data'])).id);
      sessionStorage.setItem('id', JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res['data'])).id);
      this.router.navigate(['']);
    })
    })
  }

  selectFile(event) {
    this.selectedFiles =event.target.files;
    this.currentFileUpload = this.selectedFiles.item(0);
    console.log(this.currentFileUpload);
    const reader = new FileReader();


    reader.onload = (event) => {
      this.imgURL = reader.result;
    };
    console.log(this.imgURL);
    console.log(reader);

  } }
```

**//html**

```
  <div class="container">
    <form method="POST" class="appointment-form" id="appointment-form" [formGroup]="registrationForm" (ngSubmit)="OnSubmit()" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <h2>education appointment form</h2>
      <div class="form-group-1">
        <div [class]="form-control" >
        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="firstName" placeholder="First Name" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid':submit && f.firstName.errors} " />
          <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="&#xf207;"></span>
          <div *ngIf="submit && f.firstName.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
          <div *ngIf="f.firstName.errors.required">firstName is required </div>
        </div>
      </div>
        <div [class]="form-control" >

        <input type="text" formControlName="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid':submit && f.lastName.errors}" />
          <div *ngIf="submit && f.lastName.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
            <div *ngIf="f.lastName.errors.required">LastName is required </div>
          </div>
        </div>
          <div [class]="form-control" >
        <input type="email" formControlName="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid':submit && f.email.errors}" />
        <div *ngIf="submit && f.email.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
          <div *ngIf="f.email.errors.required">Email is required </div>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div [class]="form-control" >
        <input type="password" formControlName="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid':submit && f.password.errors}"  />
        <div *ngIf="submit && f.password.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
          <div *ngIf="f.password.errors.required">Password is required </div>
          <div *ngIf="f.password.errors.minlength">Au moins 8 caracteres </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div [class]="form-control" >
        <input type="text" formControlName="adresse" placeholder="Adresse local" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid':submit && f.adresse.errors}"  />
        <div *ngIf="submit && f.adresse.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
          <div *ngIf="f.adresse.errors.required">Adresse is required </div>
        </div>
        </div>

          <div class="custom-file">
            <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile"  (change)="selectFile($event)" formControlName="pdf" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid':submit && f.pdf.errors}" />
            <label class="custom-file-label">Photo de profil</label>
          </div>
        <div class="form-submit">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="submit" value="Submit" />
      </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>

</div>
```

but console say that there is error in back-end that :

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'originalname' of undefined
>       at C:\Users\hazem\Desktop\pfe\router\user.js:114:47

Comment: check whether the request header content-type is same as the type in postman. In postman you can check it by click on 'code' under the send button.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you have not used the library ng2-file-upload Try something like this.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {  FileUploader, FileSelectDirective } from 'ng2-file-upload/ng2-file-upload';

const UploadURL = 'http://localhost:3000/api/upload';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'Upload a File';

  public uploader: FileUploader = new FileUploader({url: URL, itemAlias: 'image'});

  ngOnInit() {
    this.uploader.onAfterAddingFile = (file) => { file.withCredentials = false; };
    this.uploader.onCompleteItem = (item: any, response: any, status: any, headers: any) => {
         console.log('FileUpload:uploaded:', item, status, response);
         alert('File uploaded successfully');
     };
 }
}
```

The line

```
public uploader: FileUploader = new FileUploader({url: URL, itemAlias: 'image'});
```

is important. make sure you use the same name('**image**') in you multer middleware,
like this

```
upload.single('image')
```

Comment: what should i do in html? @TRomesh

Comment: @hazem if you are using ng2-file-upload you will have to initialize it like i have done in the above code. go through the docs

Comment: thanks you that work for me , but can not get name of image :(  , i want to save the name as a string